# Can I white-list styles in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` for which I need to allow only `bold`, `italics` and `underline` styles.

```
<div class="whitelist">
    <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold"> Hello World </span>
</div>
```

Here for example, the `red` should not work but `bold` should. Is there any thing in `CSS` to get this effect?

Basically these are contents created in WYSIWYG editor before we enforced `bold`, `italics` and `underline` styles as the only possible stlye.

Comment: Ah yes, the dreaded `font-weight:underline`.... I believe you either mean `:bold` or `text-decoration:`, my friend.

Comment: Huh, thats right! Corrected it, its always confused me xD

Comment: Bold letters are fat, so they have extra `font-weight`. Italic and Oblique are great when you need style (more specifically, `font-style`). And adding lines to your text (over, under, and strike/middle) is adding an extra `text-decoration` added to the font. Took me an age to remember them on the fly, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this by using `!important` in your style.

```
.whitelist, 
.whitelist * {
    color: initial !important; /* always force initial font color */
}
```

> The `*` means all elements inside `.whitelist`

The downside is that this is more of a blacklist where you force all the styles you don't want overridden.

### [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ygrrLpof/)

Comment: Whitelist is always safer because its hard to predict whats in there.

Comment: @Nishant – It's not possible to whitelist in CSS though

Comment: If I could mention `*` instaed of color it might have helped. But I guess that is just not there?

Comment: Nope :\ But It shouldn't be too much work to list all the major styles you dont want. `text-decoration` `font-size`, etc

Comment: Does this really work? Doesn't inline styles always override styles defined in a stylesheet? 

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in pure CSS.

You could easily make a function in javascript to search for `.whitelist` and remove any attributes not matching a whitelist, though.

Comment: The problematic part here wouldn't be to make the function that finds the `style` attribute, it would be to actually apply the whitelist (remove the properties that are not allowed) in a secure manner, leaving no avenues for CSS injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not do this in CSS, but If you don't want to use specific style for that element you can override by `!important`

For this you can use

```
.whitelist span{ 
  color : initial !important; //or put your default color
}
```